# Search Console - lock in robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

In search console when I use "see like Google"
I got this: resources not on my site are blocked by robots. How to fix this?

[image: Google Search Console - View like Googlebot]

Comment: "resources not on my site" - These are presumably blocked by the other site's `robots.txt` file - in which case you can't "fix" this! Since it is the _other site_ that is blocking these resources. (I'm assuming you don't have control of these "other sites".) But, do you need to fix this?

Comment: Don't know. Google suggests to fix in order to improve indexing. Can I don't care?